# How to determine the address range of global variables in a shared library at runtime?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

At runtime, are global variables in a loaded shared library guaranteed to occupy a contiguous memory region? If so, is it possible to find out that address range?

Context: we want to have multiple "instances" of a shared library (e.g. a protocol stack implementation) in memory for simulation purposes (e.g. to simulate a network with multiple hosts/routers). One of the approaches we are trying is to load the library only once, but emulate additional instances by creating and maintaining "shadow" sets of global variables, and switch between instances by `memcpy()`'ing the appropriate shadow set in/out of the memory area occupied by the global variables of the library. (Alternative approaches like using `dlmopen()` to load the library multiple times, or introducing indirection inside the shared lib to access global vars have their limitations and difficulties too.)

Things we tried:

- Using `dl_iterate_phdr()` to find the data segment of the shared lib. The resulting address range was not too useful, because (1) it did not point to an area containing the actual global variables but to the segment as loaded from the ELF file (in readonly memory), and (2) it contained not only the global vars but also additional internal data structures.
- Added start/end guard variables in C to the library code, and ensured (via linker script) that they are placed at the start and end of the `.data` section in the shared object. (We verified that with `objdump -t`.) The idea was that at runtime, all global variables would be located in the address range between the two guard variables. However, our observation was that the relative order of the actual variables in memory was quite different than what would follow from the addresses in the shared object. A typical output was:

```
$ objdump -t libx.so | grep '\.data'
0000000000601020 l    d  .data  0000000000000000              .data
0000000000601020 l     O .data  0000000000000000              __dso_handle
0000000000601038 l     O .data  0000000000000000              __TMC_END__
0000000000601030 g     O .data  0000000000000004              custom_data_end_marker
0000000000601028 g     O .data  0000000000000004              custom_data_begin_marker
0000000000601034 g       .data  0000000000000000              _edata
000000000060102c g     O .data  0000000000000004              global_var

$ ./prog
# output from dl_iterate_phdr()
name=./libx.so (7 segments)
    header  0: type=1 flags=5 start=0x7fab69fb0000 end=0x7fab69fb07ac size=1964
    header  1: type=1 flags=6 start=0x7fab6a1b0e08 end=0x7fab6a1b1038 size=560  <--- data segment
    header  2: type=2 flags=6 start=0x7fab6a1b0e18 end=0x7fab6a1b0fd8 size=448
    header  3: type=4 flags=4 start=0x7fab69fb01c8 end=0x7fab69fb01ec size=36
    header  4: type=1685382480 flags=4 start=0x7fab69fb0708 end=0x7fab69fb072c size=36
    header  5: type=1685382481 flags=6 start=0x7fab69bb0000 end=0x7fab69bb0000 size=0
    header  6: type=1685382482 flags=4 start=0x7fab6a1b0e08 end=0x7fab6a1b1000 size=504

# addresses obtained via dlsym() are consistent with the objdump output:
dlsym('custom_data_begin_marker') = 0x7fab6a1b1028
dlsym('custom_data_end_marker') =   0x7fab6a1b1030  <-- between the begin and end markers

# actual addresses: at completely different address range, AND in completely different order!
&custom_data_begin_marker = 0x55d613f8e018
&custom_data_end_marker =   0x55d613f8e010  <-- end marker precedes begin marker!
&global_var =               0x55d613f8e01c  <-- after both markers!
```

Which means the "guard variables" approach does not work.

- Maybe we should iterate over the Global Offset Table (GOT) and collect the addresses of global variables from there? However, there doesn't seem to be an official way for doing that, if it's possible at all.

Is there something we overlooked? I'll be happy to clarify or post our test code if needed.

EDIT: To clarify, the shared library in question is a 3rd party library whose source code we prefer not to modify, hence the quest for the above general solution.

EDIT2: As further clarification, the following code outlines what I would like to be able to do:

```
// x.c -- source for the shared library
#include <stdio.h>

int global_var = 10;

void bar() {
    global_var++;
    printf("global_var=%d\n", global_var);
}
```

```
// a.c -- main program
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <memory.h>

struct memrange {
    void *ptr;
    size_t size;
};

extern int global_var;
void bar();

struct memrange query_globals_address_range(const char *so_file)
{
    struct memrange result;
    // TODO what generic solution can we use here instead of the next two specific lines?
    result.ptr = &global_var;
    result.size = sizeof(int);
    return result;
}

struct memrange g_range;


void *allocGlobals()
{
    // allocate shadow set and initialize it with actual global vars
    void *globals = malloc(g_range.size);
    memcpy(globals, g_range.ptr, g_range.size);
    return globals;
}

void callBar(void *globals) {
    memcpy(g_range.ptr, globals, g_range.size); // overwrite globals from shadow set
    bar();
    memcpy(globals, g_range.ptr, g_range.size);  // save changes into shadow set
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    g_range = query_globals_address_range("./libx.so");

    // allocate two shadow sets of global vars
    void *globals1 = allocGlobals();
    void *globals2 = allocGlobals();

    // call bar() in the library with a few times with each
    callBar(globals1);
    callBar(globals2);
    callBar(globals2);
    callBar(globals1);
    callBar(globals1);

    return 0;
}
```

Build+run script:

```
#! /bin/sh
gcc -c -g -fPIC x.c -shared -o libx.so
gcc a.c -g -L. -lx -ldl -o prog
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./prog
```

EDIT3: Added `dl_iterate_phdr()` output

Comment: Make sure you look at [Address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)

Answer (score 0):

Shared libraries are compiled as [Position-Independent Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code). That means that unlike executables, addresses are not fixed, but are rather decided during dynamic linkage.

From a software engineering standpoint, the best approach is to use objects (structs) to represent all your data and avoid global variables (such data structures are typically called "contexts"). All API functions then take a context argument, which allows you to have multiple contexts in the same process.

Comment: Thank you, but your reply doesn't answer the original question.  

The suggestion to use context objects is valid and it is basically the same as one of the alternatives mentioned in the question ("introducing indirection inside the shared lib to access global vars"). To clarify, we chose not to do that because it would require extensive changes in the library source code, and the library in question is 3rd party software that we prefer to leave intact as much as possible.

Comment: My main point though is that if you have multiple instances of global variables, you also need multiple instances of the functions (due to PIC).

Comment: Actually I only use one instance of global variables. I want to "emulate" multiple instances by having separate shadow/backup copies of the global vars, and use `memcpy` to switch. I.e. before a call to a library function, I overwrite the lib's var from the appropriate shadow set, and after the call I save the modifications made by the library by overwriting the shadow set from the actual vars. I'll add code to the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

> At runtime, are global variables in a loaded shared library guaranteed to occupy a contiguous memory region?

Yes: on any `ELF` platform (such as Linux) all writable globals are typically grouped into a single writable `PT_LOAD` segment, and that segment is located at a fixed address (determined at the library load time).

> If so, is it possible to find out that address range?

Certainly. You can find the library load address using `dl_iterate_phdr`, and iterate over the program segments that it gives you. One of the program headers will have `.p_type == PT_LOAD`, `.p_flags == PF_R|PF_W`. The address range you want is `[dlpi_addr + phdr->p_vaddr, dlpi_addr + phdr->p_vaddr + phdr->p_memsz)`.

Here:

> `# actual addresses: completely different order:`

you are actually looking at the address of the `GOT` entries in the main executable, and *not* the addresses of the variables themselves.

Comment: I did try `dl_iterate_phdr()` and found the segment with `type=1 (PT_LOAD)` and `flags=6 (R+W)` and extracted the address range as you wrote. However, as mentioned in the question, it turned out that that address range points to the loaded ELF header which practically contains the initialization values for the global variables and some internal stuff, and is readonly due to being shared by all processes that loaded the same lib. It has not relationship to what I'm interested in: the location of the shared lib's global variables in the current process.

Comment: "It has not relationship to what I'm interested" -- you are mistaken: there *is* a `PT_LOAD` `R+W` *covers* all the global variables (that come from the given shared library). Note that there may be more than one `PT_LOAD` `R+W`, depending on which linker is used, and whether `-Wl,--rosegment` is in effect.

Comment: I wish you were right. I added the `dl_iterate_phdr()` output into the question text -- sadly it displays only one `PT_LOAD` `R+W` for that shared lib on my system  (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, GNU ld 2.30, ld-2.27.so).  `dlsym()` returns addresses that point into that region, but the actual variables are in a different address range (as obtained by `&global_var`, and printed with `%p`). I'm interested querying the latter in a generic way, but I'm starting to think there's no way to do that.

Comment: "I wish you were right." -- I *am* right, and your output clearly shows it. "dlsym() returns addresses that point into that region" -- bingo! "but the actual variables are in a different address range" -- this is where *you* are confused. These are addresses of the `GOT` entries, and *not* the addresses of the actual variables! Ooh, I see. The way you linked your program forced copy relocations. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I am wondering how `&foo` (if `foo` is an `int` global var in a shared lib) could possibly be the address of a GOT entry. You mean after executing a `int *ptr=&foo;` statement, `ptr` will point to the GOT entry? But according to C rules, the `foo=3;` assignment is equivalent to `*(&foo)=3;`, which is equivalent to `*ptr=3;` -- which is supposed to (try to) overwrite the GOT entry? This is a contradiction. `&foo` must be the address where the *value* of the variable is stored, regardless of the way this address is computed (by indexing into the GOT or not). So, still looking for a solution...