# Getting the range of addresses where global variables are stored

Tags: c, global-variables, elf

I am trying to find where global variables are stored in a binary exec (ELF).

In my final context, my exec is not executed directly, but called from another program that `dlopen`s it, so I cannot use `__data_start` and `_end`.

I looked at this post here: [How to determine the address range of global variables in a shared library at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58247922/how-to-determine-the-address-range-of-global-variables-in-a-shared-library-at-ru)
Which is indeed very interesting, but some of my shared variables are not in the range returned by Employed Russian's approach.

If put everything in a single reproducer:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 
#include <link.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define N 16

static int tab[N];
uintmax_t data_start;
uintmax_t data_end;

static int smpi_global_callback( struct dl_phdr_info *info, size_t size, void *data ){
    int p_type, p_flags;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < info->dlpi_phnum; j++) {
        p_type = info->dlpi_phdr[j].p_type;
        p_flags = info->dlpi_phdr[j].p_flags;
        if( p_type == PT_LOAD && p_flags == PF_R|PF_W ){
            data_start = info->dlpi_addr + info->dlpi_phdr->p_vaddr;
            data_end = info->dlpi_addr + info->dlpi_phdr->p_vaddr + info->dlpi_phdr->p_memsz;
            printf( "begin = %2zu ; end = %2zu\n", data_start, data_end );
            return 0; /* always the same values so return after the first one */
        }        
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){    
    int i = getpid();

    dl_iterate_phdr(smpi_global_callback, NULL);

    tab[0] = i;
    printf( "ptr: %p %2zu\n", &tab, (uintmax_t)&tab );
    printf( "ptr: %p %2zu\n", tab, (uintmax_t)tab );
    printf( "ptr: %p %2zu\n", &data_start, (uintmax_t)data_start );
    printf( "ptr: %p %2zu\n", &data_end, (uintmax_t)data_end );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And I compile it with `gcc -o myexec myexec.c -fPIC`, I get something like:

```
$ ./myexec 
begin = 93878406574144 ; end = 93878406574872
begin = 140732748611584 ; end = 140732748615005
begin = 140256805367872 ; end = 140256805368656
begin = 140256807493632 ; end = 140256807497096
tab ptr: 0x5561c513b080 93878406590592
&tab ptr: 0x5561c513b080 93878406590592
data_start ptr: 0x5561c513b060 140256807493632
data_end ptr: 0x5561c513b068 140256807497096
```

A few observations:

- the array is beyond the first range
- `data_start` is at the beginning of the fourth range
- `data_end` is just after the end of the fourth range

Is it because of some relocation that was not disabled by `-fPIC`? Can I disable it, or find the true location?

Comment: OT: Kind of interresting that the source code and the produced output doesn't match

Comment: OT: Strictly `%p` requires a `void` pointer, e.g. `(void*)&tab`

Comment: This is due to ASLR. Try putting 0 into `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`: you will see the same values across executions. Then put 2 into `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`, and you will see different addresses for each execution.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Answer (score 2):

1. Your code would greatly benefit by printing all values in hex and aligning the addresses so it's easier to compare.
2. You are returning from the callback after printing the first `RW` `LOAD` segment, but there is no guarantee that there is only one such segment (although *usually* there is only one).
3. This expression: `&& p_flags == PF_R|PF_W` doesn't do what you think it does.
4. `tab` and `&tab` are *exactly* the same.
5. You are printing `begin/end` from DSOs, but you are only interested in the main executable.
6. You are printing `&data_start` but *probably* you meant to print `data_start` instead.
7. You are using `0`th `dlpi_phdr` when you should be using `j`th one.

Correcting these mistakes, I get all the addresses in the expected range:

```
gcc -fPIE -pie tt.c && ./a.out

begin = 0x562ef3318dc8; end = 0x562ef33190a0
PHDR:   [0x562ef3318dc8, 0x562ef33190a0)
tab:    [0x562ef3319060, 0x562ef33190a0)

gcc -no-pie tt.c && ./a.out

begin = 0x403df8; end = 0x4040a0
PHDR:   [0x403df8, 0x4040a0)
tab:    [0x404060, 0x4040a0)
```

The code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <link.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define N 16

static int tab[N];
intptr_t data_start;
intptr_t data_end;

static int smpi_global_callback(struct dl_phdr_info *info, size_t size, void *data)
{
    int p_type, p_flags;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < info->dlpi_phnum; j++) {
        p_type = info->dlpi_phdr[j].p_type;
        p_flags = info->dlpi_phdr[j].p_flags;
        if (p_type == PT_LOAD && p_flags == (PF_R|PF_W)) {
            data_start = info->dlpi_addr + info->dlpi_phdr[j].p_vaddr;
            data_end = info->dlpi_addr + info->dlpi_phdr[j].p_vaddr + info->dlpi_phdr[j].p_memsz;
            printf("begin = %p; end = %p\n", (void*)data_start, (void*)data_end);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    dl_iterate_phdr(smpi_global_callback, NULL);

    printf("PHDR: \t[%p, %p)\n", (void*)data_start, (void*)data_end);
    printf("tab: \t[%p, %p)\n", &tab[0], &tab[N]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Oooh it was just stupid mistakes in my code. Thank you Employed Russian!!

Comment: @DeepFriedCamembert If the answer helped you, upvote it. If it answered your question completely, accept it. (We work for brownie points here.)

Comment: I tried to upvote it, but I need at least 15 reputation for that :( Of course I would love to if I could, because you solved my problem :)